# "Simplifying" an extension of scalars

Tags: tensor-products

Let $A$ be a commutative $\mathbb Z$-algebra and $M$ be a $\mathbb Z\oplus \mathbb Z$-module.
Then $A\otimes_{\mathbb Z} M$ is an $A\oplus A$-module.
Is it true that $(A\oplus A)\otimes_{\mathbb Z\oplus \mathbb Z} M \cong A\otimes_{\mathbb Z} M$ as $A\oplus A$-modules? It seems to me that the map given by 
$$(a_1, a_2)\times m \mapsto a_1\otimes_{\mathbb Z} (1,0)m + a_2\otimes_{\mathbb Z}  (0,1) m$$
defines a map in one direction, and that the map $$a\times m\rightarrow (a,a)\otimes_{\mathbb Z\oplus \mathbb Z} m$$
defines its inverse.

More generally, is it true/ is there a slick reason that given commutative unital $R$-algebras $A$, $B$ and $C$ such that $B\cong A\otimes_{R} C$, and a $C$-module $M$, we have
$B\otimes_C M\cong A\otimes_{R} M$ as $B$-modules?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. You ask if in general
$$
(A \otimes_R C) \otimes_C M = A \otimes_R M,
$$
when both sides make sense.
This is true; the map is $(a \otimes c) \otimes m\mapsto a\otimes cm$ with inverse map
$$
a \otimes m \mapsto (a \otimes 1) \otimes m.
$$
Of course there's a lot to check here before you believe me.

Comment: (alternatively, prove the tensor product is associative and reduce to $C \otimes_C M = M$.)